# How to solve $x \geq \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor} \frac{1}{y+\log_2{x}+i}$

Tags: inequality

How can you solve $x \geq \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor} \frac{1}{i+\log_2{x} + y}$ ?

All the variables are real and at least $1$. The variable $y$ can take the values $1 \leq y \leq \lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor$. Can we give bounds for $x$ in terms of $n$ and $y$, even if they are not precisely tight?

My attempt to understand the problem. The fraction $\frac{1}{i+\log_2{x} + y} < 1$ and therefore $ \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor} \frac{1}{i+\log_2{x} + y} < {\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor}$.    Therefore $x \geq {\lfloor\log_2{n}\rfloor}$ satisfies the inequality.

On the other hand, for $x=c$, a constant, then we need $y$ to grow with $n$ I think to make the inequality true.

Comment: Does the upper limit $\log n$ mean that $n$ is chosen in such a way it's always integer?

Comment: @Kaster I am happy to assume that if it makes things easier.

Comment: I'm just saying how can you add things up non integer times.

Comment: @Kaster Yes sorry. It is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If $\log_2(n)$ is not necessarily an integer, I suppose you want to take the sum up to $m = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$.  If you write $z = y + \log_2(x)$ your inequality says 
$$ x \ge \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{i+z}$$

For any real $z$ that is not one of $-1, -2, \ldots, -m$, the right side is a real number $f(z)$, and the inequality is true for all points on the curve $y + \log_2(x) = z$, i.e. $x = 2^{z-y}$, to the right of $x=f(z)$.  The boundary of your region is described by the curve $x = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{i+z}$, which is not particularly pleasant.  Here is what your region looks like in the case $m=3$.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to give reasonable bounds in closed form for $x$ that satisfy the inequality? For example, can we at least say that $x \geq \log \log {n}$?

Comment: @motl7: Certainly not.  When $0 < x < 2^{-y-m}$ where $m = \lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor$, all terms on the right side are negative so the inequality is true.

Comment: All my variables are at least $1$ and in particular $1/2^{y+m} < 1 \leq x$.

Comment: I updated the question a little. Does it make more sense?